# Length of sequence of linearly spaced numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to find a common formula for length of sequence (meaning number  $N$ of elements) of real numbers equally spaced at distance $R$ from some starting value $a$ (including this value) and up to some ending value $L$ so that:

$$
a \leq x(n) \leq L
$$
and

$$
x(n) - x(n - 1) = R
$$

Here first element of the sequence is $x_1 = a$, and $L$ may not be included in the finite sequence $x(n)$, so it can be that $x_N < L$. Additionally, $R > 1$ and $a < L$.

In case when $a = 1$ and $L$ and $R$ are integers, the formula for number of elements $N$ of sequence $x(n)$ will be:

$$
N = \lceil L / R \rceil
$$

Here $\lceil u \rceil$ means "ceil" function: an integer number not less than $u$. But for an arbitrary $a$ it is not as obvious. It looks like the formula should look like

$$
N = \lceil \left( L - (a - 1)\right) / R \rceil
$$

but I can't prove it. Is this formula correct?

Comment: The last element must satisfy that $a+kR\leq L<a+(k+1)R$. Subtracting $a$ and dividing by $R$ we get $k\leq (L-a)/R<k+1$ with $k$ integer. This is the definition of $[(L-a)/R]$. Therefore you have $a,a+R,...a+[(L-a)/R]R$ in the sequence. That is, $[(L-a)/R]+1$ elements.

Comment: Thanks, @blueInk, this seems to be correct, could you please post is below as an answer? However, I can't figure out how to convert your expression from $\lfloor (L - a) / R \rfloor + 1$ to $\lceil L / R\rceil$ in case $a = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot determine it precisely until you have specified at what $n$ the sequence starts and ends: do you define $x_0 = a$ or do you start at $x_1 = a$? The end point is less ambiguous: $ x_N = L$. Assuming that you start at $n = 0$, the length of the interval is $L - a$ and there are $N$ steps, each of length R, so $N \cdot R = L - a$. If you start at $n=1$, there are $N-1$ steps, so $(N - 1) \cdot R = L - a$.

Comment: I start as $x_1 = a$, but it can be $x_N < L$ as $L$ might not be always included in the sequence. I will update my question accordingly.

Comment: Bu then unless you make more assumption about L, you can only get an inequality for the number of steps.

Comment: you are right, I should have used more restrictions: $R > 1$, $a < L$. It might be simple to consider only integer numbers as well, but I don't think it's necessary.